# Unity DI. Generic Type Registration and IsRegistered method

Tags: c#, generics, unity-container

I have simple refistatiion of generic interface

```
unityContainer.RegisterType(typeof(IMyInterface<>), typeof(MyClass<>));
```

It easy allows to resolve `MyClass<MyGenericType>` on `unityContainer.Resolve<IMyInterface<MyGenericType>>` and it works.

However `unityContainer.IsRegistered<IMyInterface<MyGenericType>>()` is `False`

The questions are:
1. Why?
2. How to check if `unityContainer.Resolve<IMyInterface<MyGenericType>>` possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my investigation result.

```
public static class UnityExtenstions
{
    public static bool IsRegisteredAdvanced<T>(this IUnityContainer unityContainer)
    {
        return IsRegisteredAdvanced(unityContainer, typeof(T));
    }

    public static bool IsRegisteredAdvanced(this IUnityContainer unityContainer, Type type)
    {
        var result = unityContainer.IsRegistered(type);
        if (result == false)
        {
            var genericTypeDefinition = GetGenericTypeDefinition(type);
            if (genericTypeDefinition != null)
            {
                result = unityContainer.IsRegistered(genericTypeDefinition);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static Type GetGenericTypeDefinition(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null) return null;
        var typeInfo = type.GetTypeInfo();
        return (typeInfo.IsGenericType == true)
            && (typeInfo.IsGenericTypeDefinition == false)
             ? type.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
             : null;
    }
}
```